# Unable to locate package sublime-merge on Debian 10 32

Tags: linux, debian, sublime-text-3, apt, 32-vs-64-bit

I was able to install sublime text on debian 10 32 by following instructions on their website, https://www.sublimemerge.com/docs/linux_repositories.

Same way I tried to install sublime merge but I keep getting

```
Unable to locate package sublime-merge
```

What can I do?

I'm running 32 bit debian, wondering if this might be an issue.

Comment: List : https://www.sublimetext.com/3dev .... I.e. 64bit Debian package only.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Yes, you can post an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There are unfortunately no 32bits packages, there is a 64bits Debian package only : https://www.sublimetext.com/3dev →

https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html → 64 bit .deb → sublime-text_build-3210_amd64.deb